# How does a node acquire new blocks from the network?

Tags: blocks, node

When running a non-producer node on the EOS blockchain, how does the node receive new blocks as they are produced?  Are they sent to it from a particular node?  Can the software receive blocks from multiple nodes?  And is this accomplished via TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a nodeos process for the first time, a config file is generated automatically at `.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini` by default.

In the `config.ini` file, peers can be specified by including one or many `p2p-peer-address` entries, e.g. `p2p-peer-address = ctestnet.eosdetroit.com:1339`

These peers can be any nodeos, including block producing and non-producing nodes, so long as the nodes have `p2p-listen-endpoint` and `p2p-server-address` set.

For example, the node that the above `p2p-peer-address` example is referencing would need to have the following entries in its config:

`p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:1339`

`p2p-server-address = ctestnet.eosdetroit.com:1339`

Comment: Dose it means this nodeos is restricted to receive blocks only from these p2p peers listed in config file?